# WPF MVVM una vista con varios tipos de objetos

Tags: c#, mvvm

Hola soy nuevo en esto de MVVM y por lo que entiendo se tienen que hacer UserView y unirlas en una sola ventana y cada UserView debe de tener su modelo.

Por ejemplo tengo una clase Cliente y Direccion, cada cliente tiene una dirección.

```
public class Cliente
{
    public string Nombre {get; set;}
    public Direccion Direccion {get; set;}
}

public class Direccion
{
    public string Nombre {get; set;}
}
```

Tendría que hacer una vista para Cliente y otra para Direccion y unirla en una sola ventana.

Vista cliente

```
  <TextBox 
         Text="{ Binding Path=Cliente.Nombre}">
  </TextBox>
```

Vista Dirección

```
  <TextBox 
         Text="{Binding Path=Cliente.Direccion.Nombre}">
  </TextBox>
```

Unirlas

```
<WrapPanel>
    <Views:ClienteView />
</WrapPanel>
...
<WrapPanel>
    <Views:DireccionView />
</WrapPanel>
```

Y aquí mi pregunta en concreto como seria el modelo como le hago para unir el modelo del cliente con el de dirección.

Espero haberme dado a entender.

saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta definir ambas vistas dentro de un `UserControl` que servirá como contenedor. A ese contenedor le asignas el DataContext y a cada vista definida en el contendor, le indicas que propiedad deseas enviarle por el `DataContext`.

En el code behind del contenedor, le indicamos el contexto al mismo contenedor para enviarselo a las vistas definidas en su vista.

ViewContainer.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class ViewContainer : UserControl
{
    public ViewContainer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // definimos el contexto en la vista contenedora
        this.DataContext = new Cliente {
            Nombre  = "Nombre Cliente",
            Direccion = new Direccion {
                Nombre = "RD"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Luego definimos las vistas en el contenedor y al `DataContext` de cada vista, como binding, le indicamos que propiedad queremos enviarle:

ViewContainer.xaml:

```
<WrapPanel>
    <Views:ClienteView DataContext="{Binding Path=.}" />
</WrapPanel>
...
<WrapPanel>
    <Views:DireccionView DataContext="Binding Path=Direccion}" />
</WrapPanel>
```

Entonces en cada vista utilizas los valores pasados por el `DataContext`.

DireccionView.xaml:

```
 <Grid Background="White">
        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Nombre}"></TextBlock>
 </Grid>
```

ClienteView.xaml:

```
<Grid>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Nombre}" />
</Grid>
```

Aqui el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias deja lo intento que se me esta actualizando el VS y son 2gb y va a 100 kb/s :(